Mismatch between Terraform spec and observed state for aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration
I have a aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration Terraform specification as follows:
resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "arapbi" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.arapbi.id

  rule {
    id     = "Lifecycle"
    status = "Enabled"

    filter {
      prefix = "athena_results/"
    }

    expiration {
      days = 3
    }
  }
}

When I run aws s3api get-bucket-lifecycle --bucket=arapbi I get the following:
{
    "Rules": [
        {
            "Expiration": {
                "Days": 3
            },
            "ID": "Lifecycle",
            "Status": "Enabled"
        }
    ]
}

I'm surprised because the output of the aws command does not show "Prefix": "athena_results/" as I would expect, based on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/get-bucket-lifecycle.html
Moreover, objects in my bucket are not being expired at all, which is confusing in its own right. The way things are showing up in aws s3api get-bucket-lifecycle --bucket=arapbi, I would expect all the objects in the s3 bucket arapbi to be expired after 3 days, not just the ones under athena_results
I'm confused why (1) the output of aws s3api get-bucket-lifecycle --bucket=arapbi isn't showing "Prefix": "athena_results/" and (2) why none of my objects are being cleaned up by the lifecycle policy.

Not sure about the AWS CLI command output, but filter does exactly what you tell it to, i.e, it is applied to a subset of objects for the defined bucket prefix.

That makes sense to me, but again the rule isn't actually deleting anything even though it's been in place for several days. I'm using the CLI to try and debug why the lifecycle config isn't deleting anything. So far I'm turning up empty

Does you bucket fall into any of the categories listed here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/lifecycle-expire-general-considerations.html? Also, have the three days actually passed or not?

6 days have passed, exactly. It's a non-versioned bucket, so yes.
